# F# apply sprintf to a list of strings

Tags: f#, recursion, functional-programming

How can I best create a function (lets call it myPrint) that takes sprintf, a format string, and a list of strings as arguments and produces a result such that each element in the list of strings is applied/folded into sprintf?

i.e.

```
myPrint (sprintf "one: %s two: %s three: %s") ["first"; "second"; "third"];;
```

would produce the output

```
val myPrint : string = "one: first two: second three: third"
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note that format strings in F# are specifically designed to take a statically known number of arguments, so there's not a particularly elegant way to do what you want.  However, something like this should work:

```
let rec myPrintHelper<'a> (fmt:string) : string list -> 'a = function
| [] -> sprintf (Printf.StringFormat<_>(fmt))
| s::rest -> myPrintHelper<string -> 'a> fmt rest s

let myPrint fmt = myPrintHelper<string> fmt

myPrint "one: %s two: %s three: %s" ["first"; "second"; "third"]
```

This will throw an exception at runtime if the number of `"%s"`es in your string doesn't match the number of strings in the list.

Comment: thanks, that's exactly the kind of thing I was looking for. However, your implementation above prints the list in reverse order. Shouldn't be too hard for me to modify.

Answer (score 0):

```
List.map myPrint ["first"; "second"; "third;"]
```

Will return a new sprintf'ed List...

To just print out to console... List.iter will iterate a function over each value in a list, and perform that function - but will only work with functions that don't return a value. (i.e. printf...)

map takes an 'T -> 'U - and will convert a list of any format into any other 
So

```
let myPrint in = sprintf "%s" in
```

would be allowed, but reading your question again - it doesn't do what you want.
- you could use mapi, which adds the index in (int -> 'T -> 'U) and would let you define myPrint as

```
let myPrint index val = sprintf "%d : %s" index val
```

Which would return ["1 : first"; "2 : second"; "3 : third"] which is getting closer...

But it looks like you want a single string returned - so either to String.Join on the output of that - or use fold:

```
let final = List.fold (fun (builder, index) in -> builder.AppendFormat("{0}: {1}", index, in), index + 1) (new StringBuilder()) ["first"; "second"; "third"]
```

Comment: how would you define myPrint to get the desired output specified above?